# dvisvgm baseline in org-mode HTML export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, images

When using `#+OPTIONS: tex:dvisvgm` and exporting to HTML with org-mode, the baseline of the latex exported images does not match the baseline of the text (when using subscripts, for instance). Is there any way to correct this behavior?

Comment: Did you try exporting with `imagemagick`?

Comment: Imagemagick export seems to also misplace the baseline. I guess this question could be repeated for imagemagick

Comment: [Texfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) respects the baseline but only works for the generation of png images. Just have a try.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Texfrag works very nicely inside Emacs. However, can it be used in conjunction with the org-mode HTML export to get the fragments on the exported HTML? That would be a solution, although I cannot find how that should work in the documentation.  Simply using dvipng also seems to miss the baseline.

Comment: I just published my adaptions of `ox-html` to `texfrag`: [`oxTZA-html`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/oxTZA-html/). You can give those a try. Note, that I have used that package already for years but I never intended to publish it. So you may expect some hick-ups. Just open an issue if that happens. Currently, you need to require it in your init files it is not autoloaded. If you do not like the `base64` embedding of images into HTML pages you can switch it off by setting `orgTZA-html-image-base64-max-size` to zero.

Comment: I do not know how well `texfrag` works together with `tikz`. It would be nice if you would leave a note about that.

Comment: `texfrag` seems to work perfectly with `tikz`, even when using some libraries. It is not clear to me that it solves the original question of getting the baseline right after HTML export (I am tweaking `preview-pdf-color-adjust-method` and `texfrag-scale` to get it to look right, the baseline still seems to have the same problem), but it is surely a really good alternative to what I was trying to do. Thank you, @Tobias.

Comment: Did you `(require 'oxTZA-html)` in your init file? If `oxTZA-html` is loaded `texfrag` should work with `texfrag-scale` set to 1.0. If this does not work for you please post a [bug report for `oxTZA-html`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/oxTZA-html/issues) or maybe `texfrag`.